# Authenticator for HttpURLConnection works in Froyo but not IceCreamSandwich

Tags: java, android, http, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have this code inside a runnable, on Froyo everything works perfectly. But on ICS it says it does connect but gives me a file not found error and returns -1 as the file size.

There is no problem on ICS with a file that does not need authentication.

Is there a different way to authenticate on ICS ? or am I missing some ICS HttpURLConnection detail ?

```
Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
return new PasswordAuthentication(user,pass);
                    }
                });
URL url = new URL(URLString);

HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
c.setRequestMethod("GET");
c.setDoOutput(true);
c.connect();//connection says that it is connected
final int filesize = c.getContentLength();//file size is -1 when using ICS
c.disconnect();
```

Also i'm having trouble authenticating to a https url on Froyo, thats a secondary concern at the moment though..

Thanks for helping if you can ..

I have been away for a while, but this is what I am using now. It does work with ICS, i'm not testing with Froyo at the moment so cant say for sure if it works with both ...

```
    private void setAuthenticationCredentials(final String username, final String password) {
            Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password
                            .toCharArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been authenticating my requests using`HttpURLConnection.setRequestProperty()` like this:

```
String unencoded = username + ":" + password;
String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(unencoded.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
Log.d(getClass().getName(), "encoded: " + encoded);
// Attach as authentication header.
connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
```

However, this seems to have the opposite problem. It works on 3.0 and higher but not on 2.3.4 and below (the server apparently sends a 400, although the request isn't in the server logs). Please tell me if you get this working/have already got it working, as I will be grateful for the information.

Comment: Thanks. I am using an `Authenticator` now as well and I am not seeing any problems. It's definitely the right way to do this.